# Error Element not being rendered in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

According to documentation of [errorElement](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/error-element) in react router When exceptions are thrown in loaders, actions, or component rendering, instead of the normal render path for your Routes (), the error path will be rendered () and the error made available with useRouteError. So if i throw in error inside my component i should be able to see it inside of my error element. But i can't seem to get it unless it's from a loader or action. Here is error i am throwing-

```
const RootLayout = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState();
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
  const showMe = async () => {
  let res;
  try {
    res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/showMe", {
      withCredentials: true,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.response?.status === 401) {
      console.log("error response present");
      setUserName(null);
      setUserId(null);
    }
    if (err.message) {
      console.log(`error message: ${err.message}`);
      throw json({ message: err.message }, { status: 500 });
    }
    return;
  }
  if (res.data.user) {
    setUserName(res.data.user.name);
    setUserId(res.data.user.userId);
  }
};
showMe();
}, [location]);
return (
<>
  <Header user={{ userName, userId }}></Header>
  <main>
    {console.log("reloaded")}
    <Outlet></Outlet>
  </main>
  <Footer />
</>
);
};
```

My error message is being console logged. This is my error element-

```
const ErrorPage = () => {
const error = useRouteError();
console.log('reached here :")');
console.log(error);
let title, message;
if (error.status === 404) {
title = "Not found!";
message = "Could not find resource or page";
} else if (error.status === 500 || error.status) {
console.log("error status found");
title = "An error occured!";
// message = JSON.parse(error.data).message;
console.log(error.data);
error.data?.message
  ? (message = error.data.message)
  : (message = "Something went wrong!");
console.log(message);
// message = error.data.message;
} else {
title = "Internal Server Error";
message = "Please try again later";
}
return (
<>
  {/* <RootLayout> */}
  <PageContent title={title}>
    <p>{message}</p>
  </PageContent>
  {/* </RootLayout> */}
</>
);
};
```

Comment: You are throwing an error from a callback, e.g. the `useEffect` hooks callback body. This isn't an exception triggered ***during the render*** of the component. The error component is intended to handle ***unexpected*** errors when rendering components. If you have asynchronous callback code that potentially throws errors use a try/catch and handle accordingly.

Comment: So there is no way to get it in the error element if I throw error from useEffect hooks callback body?

Comment: Are you just trying to test the `errorComponent`? If so then just throw the error from the function body. If not, then what are you trying to test or accomplish here? Also, just FYI, the `json` and `redirect` fetch utilities are only usable in loaders/actions. They won't have any effect in React components.

Comment: When my backend server is down, if I call the showMe api inside of useEffect, I get a network error with status code 500, I want to show some default error message in the error element if i encounter this error during backend server down.

Comment: You could try abstracting the `useEffect` logic into another loader/action that *can*  actually throw errors. Could you [edit] the post to include a complete [mcve] showing the router, and routes and loaders/actions?